# Wordpress meta tag description

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-tags

I need to attach one description line to each meta tag entered into WP. For example:

tags: dog, cat, cow, attached to some post

would become:

```
dog - spoiled domestic animal
cat - doesn't care about me
cow - has brown spots
```

The purpose is to display the description line below the searched tag. I.e.:
www.wordpressite.com/tag/dog/

Would display:

```
TAG
TAG DESCRIPTION
RESULTS
```

I honestly have no idea where to start, except to create a plugin which an extra db field named "tag_description" and make some sort of a "tag management area" in the admin section however this would be my last choice. Is there an easier way?

Any help appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: WordPress got descriptions for "tags", "categories" and custom "taxonomies" built in for each added term/taxon.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I see it!, I have never used it before and I am glad I asked. I could call it tag_description( $tag_id ) right ?

Comment: Or the lower level API fn [`term_description()`](http://queryposts.com/function/tag_description/).

Comment: You should post it as an answer so I can vote you up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress got **descriptions** for "tags", "categories" and custom "taxonomies" built in for each added term/taxon.

You can use the API function `tag_description()`, or the lower level API fn [`term_description()`](http://queryposts.com/function/tag_description/).